# Not able to post file with original filename on Zapier Custom CLI APP action

Tags: node.js, file-upload, zapier, node-request, zapier-cli

I am creating a ZAPIER CLI APP, In the APP I am creating a action to upload file via the rest API. 
I'm following this example app [Sample APP](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-files/blob/master/creates/uploadFile.js) with the small change I have only one input field "file", there is no input field for "filename" in my app.
Here is my code:-

```
const uploadFile = (z, bundle) => {
  const formData = new FormData();  
  formData.append('file', request(bundle.inputData.file)); 

return z.request({
  url: 'MY API ENDPOINT',
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
.then((response) => {
  return response.json;
});
```

};

But it is not working for me this sending wrong filename to rest API. This sending a long string in place of filename. Here is what I am getting at server(API) end

> here is a sample that I receiving when using the above code:-

```
  `[name] => .eJwtj1GOwiAURffCt5QygC0sYrZAXuFpSVuKgGPUdO-DiZ_35Obm3DcJsVSIDm3wxCguuBJan8gl4OpthA2JIR7_7CWsSE7EzegWu-CTGCm0Oqu-sT1WjNXWZ_q0f1tteUC-FmLe5J7XxuZaUzGMvSAFzBQ3CCtNkEsLUCu4eWsLpSuigw1ee4RH6dy-sZ-ea9pzKnrGhRDjqOTIBnS91F5RrQZHJUwT1RMqyrn0TgzgcOKMW96leG0yX6_vg4y3O5ba3I7j-AdX6FEq:1gqcEs:zXfK_evEDwf09Yp4IhuAaqxt464
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0qvnl0
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 394106`
```

Ist there anything wrong with my code?

when I passing a file name into the file field by below code, then it is **working**, but you can see I passed a **hardcode** **filename "unicycle.jpg"**, which I want to be dynamic.

```
formData.append("file", request(bundle.inputData.file), {filename: 'unicycle.jpg'});
```

**Is there any way to do this?**

Comment: Do you have the PHP code? I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of days and my $_FILES variable is always empty, I can see yours already returned the tmp_file. When I attach a file to FormData, for some reason I can't read any of the form contents in PHP. If I just remove the file I attach, I can read other text variables in the FormData object on the PHP side :(

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Zapier doesn't see the filename once it's in our system, so if you want to name the file, you'll need the user to supply that. I'd suggest adding an input field for `filename` and mapping that into the `formdata` call.

Comment: I am using  "Zapier Email Parser" "New Email" trigger and there is no filename in the trigger response. So how we will map the filename from triggger to action?

Comment: i don't believe you can get the original filename from the file object. the best case is that it exists in the body of the email and you can map it into the file action. otherwise, i'd create a new filename based on data from the incoming email. Sorry there's not a better solution to that right now

Comment: I can create a uniques filename but what about the file extension(.pdf, .png etc). Is this possible for you to share an example of a reference to do this?